# Please add multiple sorting criteria in the Community Promotion Ads statistics page

Tags: feature-request, advertising, open-source-advertising

Community Promotion Ads are a nice way for a community to knit together some sort of shared infrastructure. One good tool for making sure these adverts is the statistics page (like, for example, [the current SO ads](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/ads/display/210389)), which currently shows the live image of the ads above threshold, their score, the date they were posted, the clicks per day they've gathered, and the total clicks.

I have two requests for this page:

- Please add the date the ad went live. I don't quite see how this is less relevant than its creation date.
- Please add the ability to sort those ads on some (hopefully all) of the data shown, and particularly on the clickthrough rate. This helps gauge the product of (how much the community is interested in the 'product') x (how good the advert is), which is useful in thinking of which ads might need improvement or retirement.

I don't know how difficult this would be to implement but it seems fairly straightforward, since you have the data right there on screen, and there's already the design infrastructure to sort answers based on multiple criteria.